# Dúvida em herança

Tags: java, herança

Estou com uma dúvida sobre herança. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
public class CovariantTest {

    public A getObject(){
        return new A();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        CovariantTest c1 = new SubCovariantTest();
        System.out.println(c1.getObject().x);
    }
}


class A {
    int x =5;
}

class B extends A {
    int x = 10;
}

class SubCovariantTest extends CovariantTest{

    @Override
    public B getObject(){
        return new B();
    }

}
```

Por que quando eu chamo `c1.getObject()` retorna `A` ao invés de retornar `B`? Se estou instanciando `c1` como `SubCovariantTest`, não deveria chamar o método `getObject()` que retorna `new B()`?

Quando crio uma instância da classe Pai como uma classe Filho

```
CovariantTest c1 = new SubCovariant()
```

Não deveria olhar para os métodos/atributos da classe instanciada `new Subcovariant()`?

Answer (score 5):

Na verdade seu código retorna `B`. Porém seu objeto `B` possui dois atributos de mesmo nome `x`.

Veja abaixo, colei seu código aqui e depurando pude inspecionar o objeto retornado:

[image: Dois atributos]

Diferentemente de métodos, você **não** sobrescreve atributos.

Para não criar um novo atributo de mesmo nome, e assim evitar conflitos, `B` deve alterar o valor do atributo declarado em `A`. Isso pode ser feito usando um bloco de inicialização:

```
class B extends A {
    { x = 10; }
}
```

Ou um construtor:

```
class B extends A {
    public B() { x = 10; }
}
```

Mas ainda assim fica a pergunta: por que o Java acessou o X de `A` e não de `B`? Simples: no método `main` você usou o tipo `CovariantTest`, cujo método retorna um `A`.

Portanto o Java fez o *binding* estático para o atributo `x` de `A`, já que o compilador determinou que o retorno seria `A`, mesmo que na execução o objeto seja do tipo `B`.

Acesso a atributos **não** é polimórfico como a métodos.

Então, mantendo os dois atributos de mesmo nome `x`, mas alterando o tipo da variável `c1`, você poderia acessar o `x` de `B`. Assim:

```
SubCovariantTest c1 = new SubCovariantTest();
```

E o resultado seria `10`, porém não é uma boa prática fazer isso.

Comment: +1, perfeito, só publiquei a minha por que já estava no meio do caminho e acho que expliquei de uma forma ligeiramente diferente :)

Comment: Explicação perfeita e clara. Fica até difícil aceitar apenas uma.

Answer (score 5):

Você está correto ao dizer que seu código deveria chamar o método que retorna `new B()`, mas de fato, é isso que ele faz. Veja abaixo:

```
public class CovariantTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        CovariantTest c1 = new SubCovariantTest();
        System.out.println(c1.getObject().x);
    }

    public A getObject(){
        System.out.println("pai");
        return new A();
    }
}

class SubCovariantTest extends CovariantTest{

    @Override
    public B getObject(){
        System.out.println("sub");
        return new B();
    }
}

class A {
    int x = 5;
}

class B extends A {
    int x = 10;
}
```

Saída:

> sub
>   5

A confusão está ocorrendo ao chamar a variável `x`, que por não estar sendo acessada através de um método `getter()`, consequentemente ele pega a variável `x` da classe CovariantTest, pois não é possível sobrecarregar variáveis, assim como ocorre com os métodos.

Se você trocar o trecho `System.out.println(c1.getObject().x);` para `System.out.println(c1.getObject().y);` e mudar a classe B para:

```
class B extends A {
    int y = 10;
}
```

na esperança de que esse código irá compilar e lhe retornar o `y` da classe B, pode esquecer, pois o compilador não conhece nenhuma variável `y` na classe A, portanto lhe retornará um erro.

Comment: Show de bola. Respostas perfeitas que clarearam a explicação. Não prestei atenção quanto ao fato de sobrescrever variáveis!